# Process jQuery function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML&PHP

I list ticket info;

```php
  <table>      
  <?php
  while($values = mysql_fetch_array($ticketInfo)){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td id="ticketPrice">'. $values['ticket_price'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td id="myBonus">'. $values['bonus']*5 .'</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="use_bonus" onclick="useMyBonus();"  id="myBonusId" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }      
  ?>
  </table>
```

When user click checkbox process a jquery script for calculate discount with use bonus and write returning data to ticketPrice ID. But there is multiple checkbox and if user click another checkbox script calculate again but I don't this. How can I process it only once?

My jquery Code;

```
  function useMyBonus(){
    myBonus         = parseInt($("#myBonus").text());
    ticketPrice     = parseInt($("#ticketPrice").text());
    checked         = $("#myBonusId").is(':checked');



    if(checked == true){
        $("#ticketPrice").text(ticketPrice-(myBonus/2));

    }else{
        $("#ticketPrice").text(ticketPrice+(myBonus/2));

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the jQuery code?

Comment: You should bind the event handler in javascript (not in the html as you do now) and unbind it when it executes.

Comment: It is always preferable to post the rendered markup, without PHP code.

Comment: By the way, your form is bound to fail as you have multiple elements with the same `name` attribute.

Comment: Additionally to @jeroen comment, your markup will fail since you have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Why not just initialize a global variable to true, make processing dependant on it being true, in processing set it to false? Ugly, but efficient.

Comment: @Lorax `$("#myBonus")` will always only return the first element with that ID assigned…

Comment: Assuming that you have more than one record in the database, your generated HTML will be invalid as it will include duplicate IDs. (For example, if you have multiple rows in your table, which element will `$('#myBonus')` select?)

Comment: Back to the drawing board :-)

Comment: You also should try to describe what are you trying to achieve, not how you have tried working it out.

Comment: Yes you are right @Lorax I will change that mistakes

Comment: @EugenRieck I don't think that recommending a non-expert javascript developer creating a global variable is a good way to teach him, more when he's using jQuery, that makes you so easy to store data on your DOM.

Comment: @Áxel I don't think that using jQuery is a good idea for a non-expert javascript developer at all. But this is just MHO.

Comment: @EugenRieck yeah, maybe you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would ensure your checkboxes are unique -

```
<table>      
<?php
$i=0;
      while($values = mysql_fetch_array($ticketInfo)){ 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td id="ticketPrice">'. $values['ticket_price'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $values['bonus']*5 .'</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="use_bonus" value="' .$i++ . "_" . $values['ticket_price']  . '"  /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }      
      ?>
      </table>
```

This would loop through all the checkboxes and continue with calculation

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function useMyBonus()
    {
        var myBonus=0;


        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('use_bonus');

        for(var i in checkboxes)
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].checked)

            {
                          var n=str.split("_");
                          //now your ticket price would be n[1], use n[1] for your bonus calculation 
                        //calculate myBonus         
            }           


        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my notice, now I have modified the code so that it is 1_42, 2_42, 3_56 and so on...basically I have ensured that a running count followed by an underscore followed by ticket price, would give me a unique string, I then split them in javascript and use ticket price n[1] for my bonus calculations

Answer (score 1):

because you creating checkbox in loop so all the checkbox have same `id` and 'onclick' function so whenever you click any of that checkbox function will get call so set unique id to checkbox and set function:

```
$('#uniqueId').click(function(){
//do your work here
});
```

or in your loop set `onclick` function to only that which you want to call this function.

Comment: True, @prestack, be very carefully with creating ids in loops, although the navigator didn't complain about that, that's wrong code.

Comment: Thank you for helps and remarks. I am new in JS/Jquery. I will be careful about ID :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any flag in your checkboxes to remind the action has been yet executed (like addClass, or jQuery.data), and in the begginning of your function check for that class or data, if it already exists simply return.